# Passing props via spread operator in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Update: The plot has greatly thickened on this component as @wawka dove deep into the documentation and found that this *should* work but there are some wonky setups within the react-router-dom v^5.0.1. I'm still working through it but, this looks like it might require a rewrite of the `myLink2` component.

Using React I have a component that I need to pass an 'id' prop to render an id on the html anchor. Starting at the lowest return level for this anchor point and working up we have:

```
// links.jsx
export const MyLink = ({children, location, ...props}) => {
  const href = "mydomain.com" + location;
  return (
    <a href={href} {...props}>{children}</a>
  )
}
export const MyLink2 = ({children, location, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <RouterLink to={location} {...props}>{children}</RouterLink>
  )
}

//components.jsx
export const Block = ({linkLocation, htmlId, children, externalLink: isExternalLink}) => {
  const EditLink = isExternalLink ? MyLink : MyLink2;
  return <div className="outer-div">
    <div className="inner-div">
      {children}
    </div>
 
    <EditLink location={editLocation} id={htmlId}>{translate('edit')}</EditLink>
  </div>
}

export const Summary = ({info1, info2, info3}) => {
  return <Block editLocation={'/edit/location/' + info2} htmlId={'i-am-id-' + info2}>
    <div>{info1}</div>
    <div>{info2}</div>
    <div>{info3}</div>
  </Block>
}
```

That `htmlId` is what I'm seeking to pass up to `myLink` to assign the anchor's id attribute yet on page render it doesn't appear. Is it because id's are protected/special? Do I need to assign the spread operator on props to the `EditLink` component? Am I missing a passing point somewhere? I'm especially confused because similar questions show the spread operator as being just the right thing to do what I'm seeking.

Guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where is a definition of SummaryBlock component?

Comment: @wawka apologies, that was a typo. I've corrected SummaryBlock -> Block.

Comment: And myLink is EditLink ?

Comment: @wawka I caught that other typo right before you commented again. Apologies!

Comment: What is MyLink2? Because this condition `isExternalLink ? MyLink : MyLink2` returns MyLink2 :)

Comment: MyLink2 = ({children, location, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <RouterLink to={location} {...props}>{children}</RouterLink>
  )
}

Updating the question with this! There's another ...props on this component as well so it should be able to accept htmlId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239953/discussion-between-wawka-and-mezzomix).

Comment: with `MyLink` it works correctly, where is `RouterLink ` code?

Comment: @SaeedShamloo when I go to the `RouterLink` definition it is thus:
```
export function Link<S = H.LocationState>(
    ...params: Parameters<Link<S>>
): ReturnType<Link<S>>;
```

As `RouterLink` has `{...props}` would it not accept an id passed?

Edit: it's coming from the react-router-dom library.

Comment: It depends on `Link` type. (it's just type definition of `RouterLink` in typescipt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By all the research, this *should* have worked. As it would not in my application the workaround was to use a third `MyLink3`. I set it to a barebones link render and pass the component to `MyLink2`.

Like so:

```
// links.jsx
export const MyLink = ({children, location, ...props}) => {
  const href = "mydomain.com" + location;
  return (
    <a href={href} {...props}>{children}</a>
  )
}
export const MyLink2 = ({children, location, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <RouterLink to={location} component={MyLink3} {...props}>{children}</RouterLink>
  )
}
export const MyLink3 = ({children, location, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <a href={href} {...props}>{children}</a>
  )
}
```